# for loop will not loop

Tags: java, for-loop

I have a for loop that I will use to compute time intervals to add to an ArrayList. The problem is that I can not prove that the for loop is being executed. Nothing is printed when using the system.out.println() statement, and nothing is added to the array from inside the loop ... any sugestions?

```
// lager tidspunkter og legger disse inn i en Array kalt tider
    tid.setTimer(16);
    tid.setMinutter(0);
    tid.setSekunder(0);
    tider.add(tid.asString());// String "16:00" is added as it should 
    System.out.println("tiden er: "+tid.asString());// gives 16:00 printed
    for(int i=0;i>12;i++){
        System.out.println("er i løkken");// gives nothing printed
        tid.increaseMinutter(30);
        System.out.println(tid.asString());// gives nothing printed
        tider.add(tid.asString());
    }
```

Comment: Just an error in the for loop condition, I consider it a typo-like error. Nothing to see here, move along.

Answer (score 20):

You mean *less than*, not greater than:

```
for(int i=0;i<12;i++){ 
//           ^
```

Answer (score 9):

You condition is wrong:
Change `i>12` to `i<12`.

Comment: Damn .. one of thouse "not seing the forrest for the trees" days here. Thanks :-)

Answer (score 5):

You have a typo in your for loop: It should be i<12

Answer (score 2):

I believe you intended to process elements from 0 to 11. Therefore the for loop should be

```
for(int i=0;i<12;i++)
```

Instead, you entered

```
for(int i=0;i>12;i++)
```

Answer (score -1):

By mistake you have written here `for(int i=0;i>12;i++)`. For loop is first initializes the value of `i` to 0 and then it checks the condition `i>12` that is false, that's why your program is not entering into the for loop block and printing nothing. If you want the for loop block to be executed type 
`for(int i=0;i<12;i++)` and all will go right.

Answer (score -1):

your Code > for(int i=0;i>12;i++) // grater than

Changes >

```
(1) for(int i=0;i<12;i++) // less than 

              OR

(2) for(int i=11;i>=0;i--) // starting from size-1
```