# Multiplying odd numbers of 1-15

Tags: java, multiplication

I've written the following code:

```
    int oddProd = 1;

    for(int count = 1; count >= 15; count++){
        if (count % 2 != 0)
            oddProd = oddProd * count;
    }
    System.out.println("Odd Product: " + oddProd);
```

Why doesn't this work? It outputs 1, and I checked, it doesn't even enter the for loop!

Comment: `for (start; WHILE_THIS_IS_TRUE; incr)`

Comment: Dupe: http://stackoverflow.com/q/10516248/589259

Answer (score 7):

```
for(int count = 1; count >= 15; count++){
```

You have the expression written the wrong way around; it is now `count >= 15` but it should be `count <= 15`.

Comment: No idea why anyone would down-vote a correct answer. 1+

Comment: @HovercraftFullOfEels Apperently some people think that answers should be downvoted on questions that should be downvoted.  Which is a stupid mentality, but I certainly have seen it.

Answer (score 5):

The middle part of the for loop is the boolean check, and yours will always be false:

```
count >= 15;
```

This won't work since it won't be true in the beginning, and your loop won't start.  Change the greter than operator to a less than one:

```
count <= 15;
```